# Java web parser with cookies?

Tags: java, html, parsing

There are some html parsing libraries available, 
but what do you do if you need to authenticate, and carry the cookies with each request?

And generally what if you need to press some button in order to get the content that you want to parse, 
for example that button calculates something, or gets some data trough websocets etc...

Is there a technology to simulate behaviour in browser (so that all js is actually working) and parse from there...?

UPDATE

Maybe for this purpose i need to embed chromium and use traditional parsers? Tough i dont understand how do i trigger a click...

Comment: I've never used it personally, but I've heard good things about [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). It is a browser automation framework that I believe supports Java. I know a friend of mine has used it in the past and has had some good success with it.

Comment: I know about them but its very slow thus it more suitable for testing... altough it might do the trick... i hope for something more suitable to be embeded in a java application...

Comment: To trigger a click perhaps you can just inspect the button and figure out what exactly it does - it probably either calls a javascript function or goes to another page with POST or GET data, all of which you can do programmatically.

Comment: not necessarily, suppose that button loops trough some data that is already on the page, and calculates something, in that case i'll have to go and see what js is executed there and rewrite in java, which is absurd... I think HTMLUnit is what i need :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HtmlUnit: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://some_url");
    final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("myform");

    final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("submitbutton");
    final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("userid");

    textField.setValueAttribute("root");

    final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();

    webClient.closeAllWindows();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks much better now... :)

Comment: I know there are some issues with it, that it can sometimes crush, or render things the wrong way... surely this will work in most cases but we all understand that small library cant do what huge browser already implemented... what do you think about my update? about embeding chromium and interact with it programatically to perfectly simulate things... ?